# JSON.parse returning unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I try parse the following JSON string (generated and returned from server) using JSON.parse:

```
[{"id":1,"username":"klebermo","password":"$2a$04$YYqryKrcmUQfwmbsnhA1Te0FghiYsirxVq.Wf.kChjpEm/uuky.fu","firstName":"Kleber","lastName":"Mota","email":"klebermo@gmail.com","credenciais":[{"id":1,"nome":"user","autorizacoes":[{"id":1,"nome":"user","authority":"user"}]},{"id":2,"nome":"admin","autorizacoes":[{"id":2,"nome":"admin","authority":"admin"}]}],"enabled":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"authorities":[{"id":1,"nome":"user","authority":"user"},{"id":2,"nome":"admin","authority":"admin"}]}]
```

but I got this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success ((index):186)
at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

My javascript code where this parsing shappens:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
var atributos = [];

$('.col').each(function(){
    var prop = $(this).data('prop');
    atributos.push(prop);
});

var url = '/' + $('.list').data('list') + '/list.json';

$.get(url, function(data){
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    $.each(json.item, function(index, item){
        var row = $('<tr id='+item.id+'>');

        for(var i=0; i<atributos.length; i++) {
            if(atributos[i] == '#') {
                row.append('<td></td>');
            } else if(atributos[i] == '.') {
                var col = $('<td>');
                col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_update">editar</button>');
                col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" class="remover" data-target="'+item.id+'">remover</button>');
                row.append(col);
            } else {
                row.append('<td>'+item[atributos[i]]+'</td>');
            }
        }

        $('table.table').find('tbody.list').append(row);
    });
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

If I try validate the JSON string in several json validation sites, and no error is displayed. The JSON is listed in the Network tab in the browser developer tool, ans it's displayed correctly too.

Anyone can give a hint of what could be wrong here?

Comment: jQuery is doing the parsing for you.

Comment: That json object has one too many square brackets at the end, is that a typo?

Comment: @Tim yes, it was. Already correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already an object. No need to parse it.
`o` at position 1 is the second symbol from `[object Object]`.